# Can't load XML file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

When I run this code:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@using System.Xml;

@{
    XmlDocument vXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    string vUrl = "https://www.herefordshire.gov.uk/info/200142/planning_services/planning_application_search/rss?search-term=brilley&search-service=search&search-source=the%20keyword&search-item=brilley";

    vXmlDocument.Load(vUrl);

    XmlElement vRss = vXmlDocument.DocumentElement;

    XmlNode vChannel = vRss.FirstChild;

    XmlNodeList vChildNodes = vChannel.ChildNodes;

    foreach (XmlNode vXmlNode in vChildNodes)
    {
        if (vXmlNode.Name == "item")
        {
            <div>
                <a href="@vXmlNode["link"].InnerText" target="_blank">@vXmlNode["title"].InnerText</a>
            </div>
        }
    }

}
```

At

```
vXmlDocument.Load(vUrl);
```

I get the error:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

The link I'm using does display an XML file, as you can see.  If I make `vUrl = http://ubeumbraco.co.uk/BrilleyApplications.xml`, then it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you provide is NOT an XML file, which `XmlDocument.Load` expects. It is a web service that returns a response in XML format.

You can first download the response string, then call `XmlDocument.LoadXml` to parse the string into an `XmlDocument` instance.

```
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    string xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(vUrl);
    vXmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlStr);
}
```

Comment: `REsponse.Stream` fits `xDoc.Load` as well.